# Can't play LOL on ubuntu 14.04 Bugsplat error

Tags: 14.04, games, crash

A few days ago I decided erase windows and try Linux, I install LOL and after the champ selection the game crashes, I was searching for some info and I try different solutions and nothing fix it.

Laptop specs:

- Dell inspiron 5521
- Intel Corei5
- Intel hd 4000

Please help!

Comment: did you use Wine? if  you have used wine give a try using Play on linux(alternative to wine and it is more advance than wine). refer this link http://linuxforcynics.com/how-to/how-to-install-and-play-league-of-legends-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For games that are not compiled to run on Linux it is better to use 'Play on Linux' since it does have some automated scripts to run some games properly.

```
$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

or (for earlier versions):

```
$ wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | apt-key add -
$ sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_`lsb_release -sc`.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```